Is there a mechanical benefit for refinements when learning transmutations?
The Promethean: The Created rulebook says several times that refinements make it easier to learn certain transmutations. For example, page 84 says:

Transmutations differ by theme and function, and each Refinement allows for the expedited learning of two of these classes of powers.

What mechanical benefit (if any) does a refinement provide when learning transmutations? Each refinement lists two transmutations, but I don't see any explanation for how exactly it's easier to learn the associated powers.
I'm currently creating my first Promethean character. It's possible this comes up outside character creation and I just haven't found it yet.

Refinements let you buy associated transformations at a lower XP cost.
On pages 89 and 119, you'll see that you get new ranks of an Affinity transmutation at (New Dot * 5), while Non-Affinity ones cost (New Dot * 7). That's what's meant by "expedited learning" — new ranks are acquired faster because they cost less.
